# Can't pull multiple values from a query in SQLite for Python

Tags: python, sqlite

So, I am trying to pull multiple values from a SQlite3 query in Python 3.5 for a single row of data.  I can get this to happen for one of my sets of data with no issues.  When I go to try and pull a different value from the returned list that I have saved as results I start getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\speedrack.py", line 183, in btn_clk
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: beamupright
```

The following code works with no problem for placing the value in disc to the cell specified in #Description.

```
def btn_clk(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.text() == "Submit":
        entry = self.mod_num.text()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("uprightsbeams.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
        results = c.fetchone()
        disc = results[2]
##            unit = results[5]
##            wgt = results[3]
##            l_price = results[4]
        print(results)
        print(disc)
##            print(unit)
##            print(wgt)
##            print(l_price)
    #Catalot No.
        col = 0
        tab_entry = QTableWidgetItem(self.mod_num.text())
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, tab_entry)
    #Discription
        col = 1
        tab_disc = QTableWidgetItem(disc)
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, tab_disc)
```

When I go and do the following:

```
def btn_clk(self):
    sender = self.sender()
    if sender.text() == "Submit":
        entry = self.mod_num.text()
        conn = sqlite3.connect("uprightsbeams.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
        results = c.fetchone()
        disc = results[2]
        unit = results[5]
##            wgt = results[3]
##            l_price = results[4]
        print(results)
        print(disc)
        print(unit)
##            print(wgt)
##            print(l_price)
    #Catalot No.
        col = 0
        tab_entry = QTableWidgetItem(self.mod_num.text())
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, tab_entry)
    #Discription
        col = 1
        tab_disc = QTableWidgetItem(disc)
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, tab_disc)
    #Color
        col = 2
        color = QTableWidgetItem(self.color_Entry.currentText())
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, color)
    #QTY
        col = 3
        qty = QTableWidgetItem(self.qty_Entry.text())
        self.form_widget.setCurrentCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, qty)
    #place holder for UN. cell
        col = 4
        un_tab = QTableWidgetItem(unit)
        self.form_widget.setCurrnetCell(self.row, col)
        self.form_widget.setItem(self.row, col, un_tab)
```

is when I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "E:\speedrack.py", line 183, in btn_clk
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
    sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: beamupright
```

What am I doing wrong that is causing this?

Comment: "no such table: beamupright" This error is as straightforward as an error message can be.

Comment: @DeepSpace I thought so as well.  But can you then explain how I can get the first piece of data from the exact same table before I try and get another piece of the information?

Comment: Where is the working code and where is the not working code? Provide a [mcve] without the unneeded GUI stuff.

Comment: The first code block I posted for the def btn_clk works.  When I change to add to it as seen in the second code block is when I get the error.  The block of code in the #Color section of the second block posted is in the first part as well, but that didn't touch the query so didn't post it there as I was wanting to keep the the MINIMAL part of posting the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows that the database you have opened is empty.

And since you are opening the database in some random directory, it's indeed likely that you get an empty one.

Always use the full path to the database file.

Comment: this solved it.  I didn't think with the db being in the same directory it would matter, but I guess I have much to learn still about accessing db's and python in general.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It worked, and then it failed.

Reason: You never closed the connection and flushed the cursor, resulting in the table becoming locked and inaccessible.

Change this section of code from:

```
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
results = c.fetchone()
```

to:

```
with conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM beamupright WHERE catalogNo=?", [entry])
    results = c.fetchone()
```

This will automatically release the connection when the query has finished running.

Comment: Alan, thank you for responding.  Unfortunately this did not fix the issue I was having.  I'm still getting the same traceback. I really do not know what is going on.  I thought that by putting in the results = that the list would be stored and I could use them for that instance of calling on the def btn_clk method.  But that is not working.